# How to change the key value of inner map in c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I'm working on map and I have following nested map and initialized with some values:

```
map<string, map<int, int> > wordsMap;
map<int, int> innerMap;
map<int, int>::iterator iti;
for(int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
{
   wordsMap[argv[i]].insert(pair<int, int>(0,0));
}
```

And after some processing I'm trying to change the content if inner map, I use following code:

```
while(some_condition)
{
  i = 0
  for( it = wordsMap.begin() ; it != wordsMap.end(); it++)
  {
   innerMap = it->second;
   int cnt = count(words.begin(), words.end(), it->first);
   if(cnt != 0){
       wordsMap[it->first][i] = cnt;
   }
  }
  i++;
}
```

In the above scenario,  How to change the value of first key (i.e. "0") and its value used while initialization of the inner map with another key-value pair?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the key of an element in an `std::map`.  Doing so would break ordering.

Instead, you must insert a new element in the map with the key you want, and delete the previous element from the map.

Comment: @Johan Thanks you, Actually I am storing the count words in a particular line in the inner map. In case there is no word found on 0th file, the entry int the inner map should not present for key "0". Any pointer to get done this in the above code.

Comment: @BSalunke:  I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: In my code "wordsMap" is vector of string. In that I'm counting no of occurrences of a particular word. Now if I want to change the inner loop first key-value pair with new key-value pair. How I can do it? or is there any way not initialize inner map while initializing the outer map?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your intend. I assume you want to save,

1. `<KEY : file_name, VALUE : <KEY : line, VALUE : words count>>`
2. And you don't want to save second map if there is no words.

So, I wrote below code.
If you want to not present second map, just keep empty map through not inserting key-value. 
Additionally, since`std::map` is an associative container, which means it is saved sorted based on Key value, you should try to avoid change the key value after saving it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef std::map<int, int>                  WORDS_COUNT_MAP_T;      //for line, words count
typedef std::map<string, WORDS_COUNT_MAP_T> FILE_WORDS_COUNT_MAP_T; //for file name, WORDS_COUNT_MAP_T

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE_WORDS_COUNT_MAP_T file_words_count_map;

    //Input dummy data for test

    //init file names
    std::vector<string> file_names;
    file_names.push_back("first");
    file_names.push_back("second");
    file_names.push_back("third");

    //get and set words count in each file
    for_each(file_names.begin(), file_names.end(), [&](const string& file_name)
    {       
        //Just for test
        WORDS_COUNT_MAP_T words_count_map;
        if(file_name == "second")
        {
            //not find words, so nothing to do
        }
        else
        {
            words_count_map[0] = 10;
            words_count_map[1] = 20;
        }

        file_words_count_map.insert(FILE_WORDS_COUNT_MAP_T::value_type(file_name, words_count_map));
    });

    //print
    for_each (file_words_count_map.begin(), file_words_count_map.end(), [&](FILE_WORDS_COUNT_MAP_T::value_type& file_words_map)
    {
        cout << "file name : " << file_words_map.first << endl;

        WORDS_COUNT_MAP_T words_count_map = file_words_map.second;
        for_each (words_count_map.begin(), words_count_map.end(), [](WORDS_COUNT_MAP_T::value_type& words_map)
        {
            cout << "line : " << words_map.first << ", count : " << words_map.second << endl;
        });

        cout << "----" << endl;

    });

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

This code will print like below,
[image]